# Talend : XML with multiple header => split the file with Talend's job

Tags: xml, talend

I've got a problem with a file i received which have multiple header  =>

[XML Pic][1]

I would like to create a job with talend to split it in many files or to create one file readable.

I tried many ways but with no success.

The file i receive is output file (*.out), not a XML at the beginning.

Thx for the help ! :)

Edit :

Thx for response :

for exemple : Initial file (*.out file) =>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02"><BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn><GrpHdr><MsgId>AI3069868076</MsgId><CreDtTm>2017-04-03T23:51:23.586</CreDtTm><MsgPgntn><PgNb>1</PgNb><LastPgInd>true</LastPgInd></MsgPgntn></GrpHdr></BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn></Document>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02"><BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn><GrpHdr><MsgId>AI4069973130</MsgId><CreDtTm>2017-04-04T21:09:41.090</CreDtTm><MsgPgntn><PgNb>1</PgNb><LastPgInd>true</LastPgInd></MsgPgntn></GrpHdr></BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn></Document>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02"><BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn><GrpHdr><MsgId>AI4069973134</MsgId><CreDtTm>2017-04-04T21:09:41.090</CreDtTm><MsgPgntn><PgNb>1</PgNb><LastPgInd>true</LastPgInd></MsgPgntn></GrpHdr></BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn></Document>
```

I would to have

File 1 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02"><BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn><GrpHdr><MsgId>AI3069868076</MsgId><CreDtTm>2017-04-03T23:51:23.586</CreDtTm><MsgPgntn><PgNb>1</PgNb><LastPgInd>true</LastPgInd></MsgPgntn></GrpHdr></BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn></Document>
```

File 2 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02"><BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn><GrpHdr><MsgId>AI4069973130</MsgId><CreDtTm>2017-04-04T21:09:41.090</CreDtTm><MsgPgntn><PgNb>1</PgNb><LastPgInd>true</LastPgInd></MsgPgntn></GrpHdr></BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn></Document>
```

file 3 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02"><BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn><GrpHdr><MsgId>AI4069973134</MsgId><CreDtTm>2017-04-04T21:09:41.090</CreDtTm><MsgPgntn><PgNb>1</PgNb><LastPgInd>true</LastPgInd></MsgPgntn></GrpHdr></BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn></Document>
```

'Cause the inital file is unreadable ! :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that:

- tFileInputFullRow schema contains just 1 field called "line" (this the default)
- tFixedFlowInput schema contains just 1 field called "content" populated with "((String)globalMap.get("row1.line"))"

Also check that tJavaRow schema looks like:

[image]

You can change field names as you want, but they must be consistent for the job.

Comment: Really big thx it works :! :) i remove from my desk my wife's portrait and put yours :p

Comment: So sorry for your wife!

Answer (score 0):

If the subject is just to generate a separate file for each record if the input file, you can proceed like that:
[image]

- tSetGlobalVar to initialize a variable called "fileCounter" with the value of 1 (will be used for output file namming)
- tFileList to iterate over the files to be converted (even if only 1)
- tFileInputFullRow to read input file 1 plain row at a time
- tFlowToIterate to iterate over each input row of the current file
- tFixedFlowInput to convert each field of the input flow to a global variable (here called "line" because of tFileInputFullRow) and reinitiate a flow (generated global variable will not be used in this example)
- tJavaRow to increment the "fileCounter" value and transmit the current row to the output file

  ```
  output_row.line = input_row.content;
  globalMap.put("fileCounter", ((Integer)globalMap.get("fileCounter"))+1);
  ```
- tFileOutputRaw to generate the output file for the current row - just have to set the filename according to the current row rank:

  ```
  ((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH")).replace(".xml", "") + (Integer)globalMap.get("fileCounter") + ".xml"
  ```

In this example, source filename is supposed to terminate with ".xml" but you can easily arrange yourself with that.

Here is the result (1 input file with 3 records = 3 output file):

[image]